# Some doubts about how Spring handle transactional behavior using AOP and proxy?

Tags: java, spring, architecture, proxy, spring-transactions

I am studying how Spring hanfle transaction and I have the following doubt.

I have this example:

```
@Transactional
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {

    // SOME METHODS
}
```

And I am asking: **Using Spring AOP what methods of ClientServiceImpl are transactional?**

I know that the correct answer is: **all the methods within the ClientServiceImpl that are declared also into the ClientService interface**

But exactly why?

I think that it could depend by the fact that for AOP Spring use the proxy pattern. So the object **ClientServiceImpl** is put inside a proxy object that should implement the **ClientService** interface (because it is a JDK proxy) and that wrap also the **SpringTransactionInterceptor** object that handle the transactional behavior.

Is it reasoning correct?

Comment: What makes you doubt your reasoning? IMHO it's perfectly fine. Maybe except  for  the rare case when Spring is forced to use CGLIB proxies via configuration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why in Spring AOP the object are wrapped into a JDK proxy that implements interfaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650355/why-in-spring-aop-the-object-are-wrapped-into-a-jdk-proxy-that-implements-interf)